# typewriting effect using generator and yield

Tags: javascript, html, promise, generator, settimeout

I am trying to create a typewriter effect using javascript, I want to write the first sentence first, then second sentence and so on.

I tried doing it using using `setTimeout` and it is working fine, but I want to add more sentences and do it using `generators` to add more sentences, but I am having really hard time to figure it out and translate my code to `generator` function because `setTimeouts` are nested and are in loops.

This is my code using `setTimeout`:

```js
const s1 = `I am sentence 1`;
const s2 = `I am sentence 2`;

s1.split('').forEach((ch, i) => {
  setTimeout(c => {
    document.querySelector('h1').textContent += c
  }, i * 70, ch)
});
setTimeout(() => {
  s2.split('').forEach((ch, i) => {
    setTimeout(c => {
      document.querySelector('h2').textContent += c
    }, i * 100, ch)
  });
}, s1.length * 70)
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
```

Please help me doing it using `generator`, thank you!

Comment: I'd not do it with a generator, but create a promise wrapper for `setTimeout` and place the code in an `async` method. This way you can write your code like it was synchronous (but of course it isn't)

Comment: @derpirscher, thanks for the advice, I also thought doing it using promises firstly, but could not figure out how to chain them, would you be able to show how can I do it? I don't know how to use promises properly in loops or nesting them and passing an increasing delay to them. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation using `generator` may look like this:

```js
function* generator(str) {
    yield* str;
}

const addSentence = (element, sentence, done) => {
  const gen = generator(sentence);
  const el = document.querySelector(element);
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const ch = gen.next().value;
    if (!ch) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      if (done) {
        done();
      }
      return;
    }
    el.textContent += ch;
  }, 100);
}
addSentence('h1', 'Sentence 1', () => {
  addSentence('h2', 'Sentence 2');
});
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: btw, `function* generator(str) { yield* str; }` is sufficient.

Comment: btw, `sentence[Symbol.iterator]()` is sufficient. you can remove `generator` entirely.

Comment: @Mulan good point, thanks! However, the question was how to use `generator` in this scenario, so I think it is important to keep `generator` in the code.

Comment: it's an okay exercise, sure. but if a patient comes to a doctor with a question, we trust the expert to provide the best advice, regardless of how misguided the inquiry may be.

Comment: @Mulan, we are not doctors here and are not dealing with life-threatening conditions (luckily) :) In programming, there are many ways in which every behavior can be implemented. The question was about the specific one. If the question had been "how to implement typewriter in the best possible way, " your approach would probably be the most appropriate. Asker sees your comment and can use it if needed, but I don't think it is right to steer my answer away from `generator` after it was accepted as a solution.

Comment: actually a lot us are doctors and software is used in critical applications in countless fields! think medical, safety, security, scientific, military, financial. this is a simple question sure, but the principle is the same: novice questions can mislead the learner and it's a teacher's responsibility to help avoid pitfalls or bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

I'd not do it with a generator, but create a promise wrapper for setTimeout and place the code in an async method. This way you can write your code like it was synchronous (but of course it isn't)

```
function delay(ms){ 
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

async function typewriter() {
  let sentences = ["...", "...", ...]

  for (let s of sentences){
    let e = document.querySelector(...); //find the correct element 
    for (let c of s){
      e.textContent += c;
      await delay(50); //wait after each character
    }

    await delay(100); // wait between sentences 
  }
}
```

This is just the basics. Don't know how you will find the respective DOM element for each sentence. I just assumed you have some way and the elements will exit ( thus this code will throw an error if it doesn't)

Comment: `for (let c of s.split(""))}` should be `for (let c of s) {` with opening bracket and without splitting. it makes `of` with `Symbol.iterator`.